# RL circuit with PWM as an input turn the ground to negative

Tags: mosfet, pwm, inductor

RL circuit with PWM as an input turn the ground to negative.

I'm trying to limit the current of RL circuit by using PWM.
This how it works, for 15 ms the circuit receives constant voltage to charge the coil a bit faster and after that the PWM step in to reduce the current/to keep it low.

On LTspice simulation everything looks as expected, but when I measure my circuit with an oscilloscope when the PWM starts the input voltage goes to a negative value that directly relate to the voltage value of the inductor.

[image: the circuit in LTspice, L4 has intrinsic resistance of 1.6Ω]
the circuit in LTspice, L4 has intrinsic resistance of 1.6Ω

[image: This is what i get when running the simulation. the red line is the current across R10. And in gray it's the voltage measured in the Drain of M4]

This is what i get when running the simulation. the red line is the current across R10. And in gray it's the voltage measured in the Drain of M4

[image: the blue line is the voltage on the 1Ω resistor in serias to the inductor]
the blue line is the voltage on the 1Ω resistor in serias to the inductor

[image: This is the actual circuit]
This is the actual circuit, Out 1 is Microcontroller PWM Output

the input voltage comes from a MOSFET.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Andyaka 
now that the built-in Stack Exchange image upload facility is fixed I updated my question with few images to clarify my issue. Thank you all very much!

Comment: Not sure, if I am  missing something, but the supply voltage looks shorted to ground via M4, L4, R10, no ? (Assuming that "VIN" is a positive supply)

Comment: @tobalt Yeah, so the load is the inductor and the internal resistance is around 1.66Ω.
I added 1Ω power resistor in series to the coil for testing purposes, so I also added it to the simulation. but yeah it's high amps.

Comment: @tobalt
the short answer, it isn't shorted to the ground